# Email not to admin, When user create an account

Tags: 7

I want to send an email to another email, rather than admin Email, When user create an account

Can Anybody tell me how to do that . I am using drupal 7

Thanks

Comment: you can use rules module for that event should be after creating an account-> action send email to abc@abc.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download, install & Enable [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.
2. Goto

   Admin -> Configuration -> Rules

-> Click on **Component** tab -> Add Component

-> Select **Action set** -> In **Component Plugin** ->

Name: Send email to inactive user

Datatype: User,

Label:active_user,

Machine_name: active_user

Usage: Parameter

-> Add action -> data selector: active_user

-> Enter the subject & body & save

-> Go back & Add new rule

-> React on Event : **After Saving a new new user a/c**

-> **Add Action**  -> Select **Schedule Component Evaluation**

-> **Value** : Choose your component

-> Identifier : [account:uid]

-> Data selector : account

If you have any doubt then you may **[CLICK](http://webwash.net/tutorials/how-send-follow-emails-using-rules-scheduler-drupal-7)**